# Mesh as a plane surface calculation

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

I tried this code to calculate the mesh surface, It gives me a right value when I apply it on a simple cube, but a wrong one when it's this leaf mesh. As you can see, there's a difference between the blue output value (It's in meters unit) in Blender console and the area surface from 3D Print Panel.

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.data.objects['tomato_leaf']

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

area = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces)
print(area)

bm.free()
```

Comment: Did you try to (1) apply the scale and (2) triangulate the object?

Comment: No, Is there a mathematical formula for that ?

Comment: Try using the bmesh ops: [triangulate](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.triangulate), [transform with object matrix](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.transform)

Comment: But how can I deal with this two function ?